# Dis-/advantages for faculty position in private vs public university hospitals in Germany

Tags: university, germany

In Germany, several private medical universities (e.g. MSH Medical School Hamburg) have formed and partnered with companies such as Helios and alike running the hospitals. Looking for a new senior position (patient care and research) in a university hospital - what are the advantages/disadvantages compared to public universities? E.g. regarding "freedom of research", economical interest of the private holding vs. public mandate in public university, burocracy of separation of patient care vs. research...?

I have seen similar [discussions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/17584/133746) for the US, but I am asking specifically for Germany, since I am not sure if these are comparable to the big US private universities.

Comment: In which sense *are* these "faculty" positions? Would you be a proper professor at a university?  Or would you be a regular employee of the hospital and only be a Hon-Prof or Apl-Prof at the associated university?

Comment: I think a problem with this question, compared to the one you link to, is that it is rather narrow: It is about medicine (which at least in Germany differs in quite a few aspects from many other fields the way university works), and it is about private medical universities in Germany, of which there are very few (to be honest, to me only Witten-Herdecke comes to mind, can you at least give a few examples)?  So probably only very few people here might know about this.

Comment: Specifically, are you talking about private medical universities, or are you talking about private hospitals being a "university hospital" of some public university?

Comment: @user151413 Updated text in Q: private medical universities (e.g. MSH Medical School Hamburg) plus companies such as Helios and alike running the hospitals.

Comment: Ok, so it is specifically about *private hospitals* serving as university hospitals for *private universities*, nor for public universities (not sure the latter exists, but it might)?  I guess this might then be linked to the status of professors in general at private universities in Germany.  Though my feeling is that it will be hard to give a canonical answer due to the small number of private universities in Germany.